# How to solve asyncio run error in DiscordBot

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'd like to ask everyone for some help. This is what I'm running on Replit. After updating pip, I suddenly encountered the following error message, which might be due to an incompatibility issue between the packages or Python:

Thank you all for your help

py version:3.8 asyncio version:3.4.3

Error Msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 101, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "main.py", line 94, in main
    async with bot:
AttributeError: __aexit__
  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
```

The original code

```
async def main():
    async with bot:
        await load_extensions()
        await bot.start(os.environ['Token'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keep_alive.keep_alive()
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I try to reinstall some package but not work

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using?

Comment: thankyou for your reply,  discord.py is 1.7.3

Comment: The [`async with bot: ...` statement](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#asyncio-event-loop-changes) has been introduced in discord.py 2.0

Comment: Oh,thankyou!!that fixed it after updated discordpy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was already mentioned, OP is using very modern language constructs with 2 year old version of discord, which is excatly what it's complaining about. Keep close attention to the error message and there'd be no issue.